# what happens if multiple users call C# File.WriteAllText at the same time to the same location?

Tags: c#

tldr; If multiple users/instances of an application call File.WriteAllText() to the same filepath at the same time, what will happen? will the call throw an exception, will the call throw an exception and corrupt the file, will the call 'succeed' but still potentially corrupt the file, will the OS schedule one to happen after the other or will some other thing happen?

We have an application that saves config settings each time they use our application's main feature. The config is saved to the app's install folder, to the same path each time. We now have a client that wants to have multiple users running the application from the same install path. If a conflict results in the config not saving that's not an issue, but if the conflict results in corruption it would be inconvenient. I just need to know the likelihood of the call corrupting the file and not throwing an error?

Any help or links to sources would be greatly appreciated, I couldn't find anything when I was looking.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
With FileStream, and with FileShare.Read, if another user tries to read the file in the middle of a write, will he get the earlier version of the file? or will he get an incomplete file? this is not a large file being written, but would it be necessary to set it to FileShare.None and add retries to the file.read as well or not?

Comment: "Undefined behavior" is my guess.  I'd try having the application wanting to update lock the file first.  If that succeeds, write, else say someone else is doing it.  Or re-write it to avoid this design flaw.

Comment: Well, you can find out for yourself, by running a few threads the update the file. But @DaveS's advice is the correct way to go.

Comment: I've managed to produce an error, 'file access denied', so it does seem to be locking the file properly, just need to implement some kind of retry now

Comment: Is there much point in retrying? If two processes are overwriting the entire file, then there can only ever be one winner: the one that writes last. If you have two applications writing to the file at once without considering the other's changes, who should be the winner?

Comment: If you want to know what it does internally, you can just look at the code for [`File.WriteAllText`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,3768ad284a63029f). Drilling down through the function calls, you will see that it uses a `StreamWriter` to write the data, which creates the file via a `FileStream` which uses `FileShare.Read`, which means that the file will be locked for writing until the call to `WriteAllText` completes.

Comment: On a different topic, why is it a global config instead of per-user? Using a global config is a great way to confuse and annoy your users when their config keeps changing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it produces an exception (I ran four instances of the application and closed them all at the same time, all but one threw an exception), File.WriteAllText() appears to lock the file. Just to be safe though, FileStream seems to give the ability to do this explicitly

```
using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
    writer.Write(jsonString));
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` uses a `FileStream` internally with the `FileShare.Read` option, so no need to do this. Also, `FileStream` doesn't have a `Write` method that takes a `string`, so unless `jsonString` is a `byte[]`, that call is going to fail.

Comment: @Herohtar is right. You can follow the chain here: [WriteAllText](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L840), [InternalWriteAllText](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#L884), [StreamWriter constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs#L180), [CreateFile](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs#L224)

Comment: ah, good to know, that will make the code much simpler to keep it as file.writealltext, thanks